# Sakurai's explanation of the dipole approximation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering, perturbation-theory, approximations, dipole

In chapter 5 of Sakurai's *Modern Quantum Mechanics* (3ed), he considers the dipole approximation for an electron absorbing electromagnetic radiation due to a harmonic electromagnetic potential.

In the end, we obtain an "absorption cross section"
$$\sigma_{\text{abs}} = 4\pi^2\alpha\omega_{ni}\lvert \langle n \lvert x \lvert i\rangle \lvert^2 \delta(\omega - \omega_{ni})$$
where $\alpha \approx \frac{1}{137}$, $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac delta distribution, $\omega_{ni} \equiv \frac{E_n - E_i}{\hbar}$, and $\omega$ is the frequency of the radiation field. Then, Sakurai integrates $\sigma_{\text{abs}}$ as a function of $\omega$ with respect to $\omega$ and obtains:
$$\int d\omega \sigma_{\text{abs}}(\omega) = \sum_n 4\pi^2\alpha\omega_{ni}\lvert \langle n \lvert x \lvert i\rangle \lvert^2.$$

I would have thought that
$$\int d\omega \sigma_{\text{abs}}(\omega) = 4\pi^2\alpha\omega_{ni}\lvert \langle n \lvert x \lvert i\rangle \lvert^2,$$
i.e., the same result as Sakurai, but without the summation over $n$.

1. Where does the summation $\sum_n$ come from?
2. What is the physical meaning of $\int d\omega \sigma_{\text{abs}}$?

Comment: You want to integrate over all dipole absorption frequencies, hence you need to sum over $\omega_{ni}$. As about what it means,- by the it's units of $cm^2/s$ it's probably some sort of dipole overall absorption cross section in whole spectrum per time unit.

Comment: Sakurai seems to have missed out writing all the summation signs over $n$ for the $\sigma_{\text{abs}}$ before that step. For any single transition to $n$ there is one term, and the absorption cross section should have every transition included. i.e. the summation sign was already there before the integral is introduced to take care of the Dirac delta distribution.